# How to determine gain from a bode plot

Tags: amplifier, bode-plot

Given this bode plot from an OP-Amp Amplifier:

[image]

What is the method for determining the voltage gain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of determining gain is to look at the Y axis for the frequency of interest.  A Bode plot is log(gain) as a function of log(frequency).  Basically, it tells you gain directly.